# Difference between FB JS Events: auth.login/auth.logout and auth.sessionChange

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working with the Facebook Javascript SDK and I'm tweaking the user-login system for my website. I'm wondering what the difference between auth.login/auth.logout and auth.sessionChange. As far as I can tell, auth.sessionChange can enable a developer to accomplish everything auth.login/auth.logout can and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, auth.sessionChange can do what auth.login/auth.logout does,but can also detect when a users session has changed in other cases, such as a password reset.